# Is it possible to print linebreaks in a string in Python

Tags: python, sql, string, line-breaks

I have a string that I want to edit and print again but preserve the \n line breaks without actually breaking the line. To illustrate with an example; I want to manipulate the string below (repeat it 3 times in a row) and print it. When I print it I want it to be in the same format (including \n's) and not in separate lines.

```
"left join recommendation_customer_action rca ON rca.analysis_id=a.analysis_id\nleft join zipcode_electric_region reg ON reg.zipcode = addr.zip\nleft join carbon_conversion_factor ccf ON ccf.energy_type_id = aes.energy_type_id AND ccf.region_id = reg.region_id\nwhere (fs_stages.label = \"First Audit\" AND r.recommendation IS NOT NULL) OR (fs_stages.label = \"First Screen\" AND sppc.savings IS NOT NULL) OR (fs_stages.label = \"Queue\") OR (fs_stages.label = \"Disqualified\")\ngroup by a.analysis_id"
```

ie I don't want:

```
left join recommendation_customer_action rca ON rca.analysis_id=a.analysis_id
left join zipcode_electric_region reg ON reg.zipcode = addr.zip
```

etc...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#repr) built-in to print linebreaks as `\n`:

```
>>> mystr = 'a\nb'
>>> print mystr
a
b
>>> print repr(mystr)
'a\nb'
>>> print repr(mystr)[1:-1] # This will get rid of the apostrophes added by repr
a\nb
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) to get the `'\n'` as is and use `str.strip` or slicing to remove the `''` returned by `repr`:

```
>>> s = "left join recommendation_customer_action rca ON rca.analysis_id=a.analysis_id\nleft join zipcode_electric_region reg ON reg.zipcode = addr.zip\nleft join carbon_conversion_factor ccf ON ccf.energy_type_id = aes.energy_type_id AND ccf.region_id = reg.region_id\nwhere (fs_stages.label = \"First Audit\" AND r.recommendation IS NOT NULL) OR (fs_stages.label = \"First Screen\" AND sppc.savings IS NOT NULL) OR (fs_stages.label = \"Queue\") OR (fs_stages.label = \"Disqualified\")\ngroup by a.analysis_id"
```

Slicing:

```
>>> print repr(s)[1:-1]
left join recommendation_customer_action rca ON rca.analysis_id=a.analysis_id\nleft join zipcode_electric_region reg ON reg.zipcode = addr.zip\nleft join carbon_conversion_factor ccf ON ccf.energy_type_id = aes.energy_type_id AND ccf.region_id = reg.region_id\nwhere (fs_stages.label = "First Audit" AND r.recommendation IS NOT NULL) OR (fs_stages.label = "First Screen" AND sppc.savings IS NOT NULL) OR (fs_stages.label = "Queue") OR (fs_stages.label = "Disqualified")\ngroup by a.analysis_id
```

`str.strip`:

```
>>> print repr(s).strip("'")
left join recommendation_customer_action rca ON rca.analysis_id=a.analysis_id\nleft join zipcode_electric_region reg ON reg.zipcode = addr.zip\nleft join carbon_conversion_factor ccf ON ccf.energy_type_id = aes.energy_type_id AND ccf.region_id = reg.region_id\nwhere (fs_stages.label = "First Audit" AND r.recommendation IS NOT NULL) OR (fs_stages.label = "First Screen" AND sppc.savings IS NOT NULL) OR (fs_stages.label = "Queue") OR (fs_stages.label = "Disqualified")\ngroup by a.analysis_id
```

---

**Second alternative** is to use [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) and replace `'\n'` with `'\\n'`:

```
>>> print s.replace('\n', '\\n')
left join recommendation_customer_action rca ON rca.analysis_id=a.analysis_id\nleft join zipcode_electric_region reg ON reg.zipcode = addr.zip\nleft join carbon_conversion_factor ccf ON ccf.energy_type_id = aes.energy_type_id AND ccf.region_id = reg.region_id\nwhere (fs_stages.label = "First Audit" AND r.recommendation IS NOT NULL) OR (fs_stages.label = "First Screen" AND sppc.savings IS NOT NULL) OR (fs_stages.label = "Queue") OR (fs_stages.label = "Disqualified")\ngroup by a.analysis_id
```